# Parameter 0 of constructor in com.Client required a bean of type 'com.NotificationsClient' that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have the following Feign client:

```
    @FeignClient(name = "notifications")
    public interface NotificationsClient{
    
        @PostMapping(value = "/", // TODO
                consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        void createEvent(Request request);
    }

.....

@Service
public class Test {

  private NotificationsClient notificationsClient;

  @Autowired
  public Test(NotificationsClient notificationsClient) {
    this.notificationsClient= notificationsClient;
  }
  ...
}
```

I added dependency:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
```

I added classpath scan

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.service"})
```

But during startup I get:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.service.Test required a bean of type 'com.service.NotificationsClient' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.service.NotificationsClient' in your configuration.

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.Client required a bean of type 'com.service.NotificationsClient' that could not be found.
```

Do you know how I can fix this?

EDIT: Test project

https://github.com/rcbandit111/feign_missing_client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably to help you I would need more context, nevertheless, what I've missed on your configuration was the annotation `@EnableFeignClients`.

If you already have this annotation in your main class, please give more context so we can try to help you.

**[EDIT - 1]**

After evaluating the complete code, What's the problem here:

Your launcher class that has the @SpringBootApplication is under the level of a package so Spring will automatically scan all the classes that are INSIDE the level of where this class is placed and all nested subpackages.

Solution: move your Application.class (the launch class) to the `com.test` level.

In more detail, you have an application with the following structure:

```markdown
.
└── src/main/java/
    └── com.test/
        ├── internal.commons.webhook/
        │   ├── dto/
        │   │   └── ...
        │   └── service/
        │       ├── PushNotificationClient.java(your feignClient)
        │       └── ...
        └── portal.account.platform.service/
            ├── Application.java (your Launch Class)
            └── WebhookPlatformClient.java
```

To solve the problem you should follow this structure so in this way, all components inside `com.test.*`, will be automatically scanned (No need to use the `basePackages` after this change)

```markdown
.
└── src/main/java/
    └── com.test/
        ├── internal.commons.webhook/
        │   ├── dto/
        │   │   └── ...
        │   └── service/
        │       ├── PushNotificationClient.java(your feignClient)
        │       └── ...
        ├── portal.account.platform.service/
        │   └── WebhookPlatformClient.java
        └── Application.java (your Launch class)
```

**[EDIT - 2]**

If you really need to keep the first structure, you'll need to tell your spring boot application (the launch class) which packages it should scan (`@ComponentScan`) and also, you need to tell which packages are the feignClients `@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = "com.test.internal.commons.webhook")`.

Follow the example and test it:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = "com.test.internal.commons.webhook")
@RefreshScope
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@Slf4j
@ComponentScan({"com.test.portal.account.platform.service", "com.test.internal.commons.webhook"})
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

Thanks for sharing more, if you need more context, please tell me :)
Regards,

Comment: Give me some time. Today will push a prototype project so you can run the code locally.

Comment: Please try this code: https://github.com/rcbandit111/feign_missing_client

Comment: The thing is that all code under `portal.account.platform.service` is located in a dependency jar. In that case is there some other solution?

Comment: I have just updated and seems that [EDIT - 2] would be what you need.